# Error unterminatet quoted string

Tags: command-line, raspberrypi

Here is my code (it is run when the RasPi boots up

```
sudo apt-get update
echo Thank you for waiting, welcome back Rhys
echo ------------------
echo  RHYS'  RASPBERRY PI
cat /proc/meminfo
fi
cat /proc/version
fi
df -h
fi
free
fi
hostname -I
fi
1susb
fi
echo ------------------
```

Comment: The problem is it says syntax error:undetermined quoted string.

Comment: What are all those `fi` lines supposed to do? They make no sense, as `fi` is there to terminate an `if` block/statement, which you don't use there anywhere.

Comment: It also needs to be `lsusb` and not `1susb`.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have to admit, that took me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a closing quote in

```
echo  RHYS'  RASPBERRY PI
```

If you really need that quote in `echo` do it this way:

```
echo  "RHYS'  RASPBERRY PI"
```

Comment: Now it shows the error syntax error fi unexpected

Comment: Who wrote that script? What all that `fi` are supposed to do?

Comment: Remove all that `fi` and change `1susb` to `lsusb` too.

Comment: Don't know, got it from a website

Comment: You probably copied only a part of a script.

Comment: Thank U, your answer works, if U edit your answer to say everything U did in the comments I will approve it 